# CSS Grid - Rows to be same height (with a max height)

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to make my rows have the same height in a CSS grid, but at the same time, there should be a max height specified by vh. What I would want, is that if there are 4 rows, with a max height of `100vh`, and the current largest height out of the 4 rows is `70vh`, I would want all the rows to be `70vh`. However, if the largest height is supposedly `120vh`, I want all the height of the rows to be `100vh`. Is there a way to do so? Below is my code thus far, I am new to CSS grid so do help me out! If there are any simpler ways to achieve what I want to do, please help guide me, thank you!

```
.project-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    row-gap: 1%;
    grid-template-areas: "card" "activities" "requirements" "quotations" "notations"
}

.card-row {
    grid-area: card;
}

.activities-box {
    grid-area: activities;
    overflow: auto;
}

.requirements-box {
    grid-area: requirements;
    overflow: auto;
}

.quotations-box {
    grid-area: quotations;
    overflow: auto;
}

.notations-box {
    grid-area: notations;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

With this, the rows all follow the same largest height, but there is no max height set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply set `max-height` to the grid items:

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  row-gap: 5px;
}

.box > * {
  max-height:100vh;
  overflow:auto;
  border:2px solid red;
  background:#f2f2f2;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div><div style="height:50vh"></div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

And with content bigger than 100vh;

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  row-gap: 5px;
}

.box > * {
  max-height:100vh;
  overflow:auto;
  border:2px solid red;
  background:#f2f2f2;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div><div style="height:130vh"></div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

may be use the `repeat` function which has syntax is `repeat(times, measurement)` and of course you should set the width which will devided into (times) you set

```
.project-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
    row-gap: 1%;
    grid-template-areas: "card" "activities" "requirements" "quotations" "notations"
}

.card-row {
    grid-area: card;
}

.activities-box {
    grid-area: activities;
    overflow: auto;
}

.requirements-box {
    grid-area: requirements;
    overflow: auto;
}

.quotations-box {
    grid-area: quotations;
    overflow: auto;
}

.notations-box {
    grid-area: notations;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: okay noted, i did not know of a repeat() function inside grid layout, will change to that, seems cleaner. thanks!